# How to move set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, lateral-join

I try this

```
select created_at, 
sum((json_array_elements(shipping_lines::json) ->> 'price')::float) as shipping_price
from t1
group by 1
```

It show Error:

> ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function
> calls LINE 5: sum(((json_array_elements(shipping_lines::json) ->>
> 'price')...
> ^ HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.

How to fix this using Lateral From? I read [this PsSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html) but not really understand Lateral function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be:

```
select t1.created_at, sum((x.obj->>'price')::float)  as shipping_price
from t1
left join lateral jsonb_array_element(t1.shipping_lines::jsonb) as x(obj) on true 
group by 1
```

Or, you can compute the `sum()` in the lateral join itself, which avoids the need for outer aggregation (assuming that `created_at` is unique in the table to start with):

```
select t1.created_at, x.shipping_price
from t1
cross join lateral (
    select sum((x.obj->>'price')::float) as shipping_price
    from jsonb_array_elements(t1.shipping_lines::jsonb) as x(obj)
) x
```

Note that I slightly changed the query to use `jsonb` instead of `json`: this new datatype is more flexible and efficient than `json` (even if it won't make a real difference here, it should be preferred whenever there is a choice).

Comment: Why it is `LEFT JOIN on True` on first answer and not Cross join? What is the difference? you miss the `s` in `jsonb_array_elements`

Comment: @HaoHao: that's in case the `shipping_lines` array is empty. In that case, `cross join lateral` would return no row, and the original row would be filtered out.

Comment: So the second answer would also `LEFT JOIN on True`?

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm.  Move the logic to the `from` clause:

```
select created_at, sum( (j->>'price')::float) as shipping_price
from t1 left join lateral
     json_array_elements(shipping_lines::json) j
     on true
group by 1
```

Comment: oh, You miss a `(`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a common table expression to do it later.

e.g.

```
with cte1 as
(
select created_at, 
(json_array_elements(shipping_lines::json) ->> 'price')::float) as c1
from t1
)
select created_at, 
sum(c1) as shipping_price
from cte1
group by 1
```

Very similar to above answer but easier to read imo.